# Como poner el nombre que aparece en el icono de la aplicacion

Tags: android-studio

cuando creo una aplicación el icono de esta aplicación que aparece en el escritorio muestra un nombre diferente al que tengo puesto en el `strings.xml`

```
<string name="app_name">Nombre UNO</string>
```

En la barra del menu tengo puesto otro diferente.

```
<string name="titulo_app">Nombre DOS</string>
```

Pues cuando creo el apk el nombre que aparece en el icono es el que tengo puesto en el `Toolbar`.

No se si es porque tengo creadas dos Clases y las dos tiene un `strings.xml`, pero en la segunda solo tengo puesto en "Nombre UNO"

Como puedo cambiar el nombre del icono ?

Gracias.

Comment: el nombre del ícono siempre es el nombre que tiene la primera actividad.

Comment: Hola @Socu, revisa el archivo AndroidManifest.xml de donde toma la etiqueta que asigna el nombre android:label= ???

Comment: En mi caso, el nombre que aparece en el icono, es el String de la activity que lanza la App. En mi caso ActivityMain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes revisar dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de donde toma la etiqueta que asigna el nombre, regularmente se toma desde `strings.xml` con la entrada `app_name`:

```
<application
     android:label="@string/app_name"
```

pero en tu caso posiblemente se este tomando el nombre de otra entrada o archivo e incluso este definido directamente el nombre de la aplicación:

```
 <application
      android:label="mi aplicacion"
```

Comment: si en **AndroidManifes.xml** tengo puesto **android:label="@string/titulo_app">** que es el titulo que tengo puesto en el menu "Nombre DOS" pero no es este el que quiero que aparezca en el nombre del icono.

Comment: Recuerda que el archivo se debe llamar strings.xml y debe estar dentro del directorio /values

Comment: si, así se llama y esta en values

Comment: @SoCu me parece que no te refieres al nombre de la aplicación si no al que se muestra en el toolbar.

Comment: Así es, no quiero que sea el mismo, en el toolbar quiero que aparezca uno, y en el nombre del icono que se crea de la aplicacion que parezca otro, por ejemplo en el toolbar que apareceza "Documentos" y en el icono "Docu"

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el nombre del Activity en el archivo **strings.xml** en tu carpeta de values.

Ya que ademas de aparecerte el nombre de la app, también están los titulos de **cada una** de las actividades, los cuales son mostrados en el Toolbar.

Aquí el nombre de la app:

```
<string name="app_name">Mi_aplicacion</string>
```

Y aquí el título de una activity:

```
 <string name="title_activity_main">Titulo_Toolbar</string>
```

Espero que sea de tu ayuda.

PD: (El valor que tengas en "app_name" será el nombre que aparcerá en el icono de la app, aunque en ocasiones, suele aparecer el nombre de la actividad principal de tu aplicación.)

Comment: Asi es como lo tengo puesto en **app_name** he puesto **Docu**, y en **titulo_app** he puesto **Documentos**, y lo que me aparece en el icono es **Documentos**, vamos que si me tiene que aparece lo que tengo puesto en **app_name** _no me aparece_ Hay algun archivo que se pueda cambiar esto, me refiero a que no sea desde el mismo Android Studio, a ver si por lo que sea no se llega a cambiar en ese archivo.

Comment: entonces hay forma de saber porque no trabaja como tiene que trabajar android studio para que cree el apk como se le dice que tiene que ser, hay solucion ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que quieres tener un ***nombre para la App (el que aparece con el ícono) y otro nombre para el Toolbar (por defecto toma el mismo de la App)***. Si es así entonces lo único que tienes que hacer es AGREGAR la propiedad TITLE.

```
app:title="@string/nombre_que_sea"
```

Al *toolbar* para que tome ese nombre que le asignes en el *String*.

Saludos y espero sea eso lo que buscas ;)